# typing skill improving apps specifically for coding

Tags: keyboard

I have developed some bad typing habits over the years that require me to look down at the keyboard from time to time. I was wondering if there are any apps or softwares that teach coding specifically for coding maybe. I have taken some free typing tests for the popular typing instruction apps and they all say I do not need to use their app. I am seeking perfection I guess but I have noticed that other people code faster than I do and never look at their keyboards.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be a pretty cumbersome and tedious journey to fix old habits. I'd suggest looking up touch typing resources.

This one looks super fun to get through. Pretty visuals and satisfying 'gameplay' while also emphasizing good finger placement and usage.
https://www.typing.com/student/lessons

I don't think there's any difference between normal keyboard usage and "coding" keyboard usage so no need to search for anything special.

Remember that it's important to have the right fingers reach for the right keys!